# How to find out which field a text box is linked to on a form? (Opposite direction of the ControlSource Property)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with multiple text boxes and want to select the one that is linked to a specific field in my dataset.

What I'm trying to do is basically the opposite direction of the ControlSource property... I know the field and want to find the associated text box.

E.g.: My dataset consists of the fields : Height, hair colour, weight, shoe size.
I have a form equipped with text boxes (for data entry) for each and every one of those fields.
I now want to select the text box linked to the field "weight"....

I could cycle through the controls on the form without a question, but is there a property of the text box telling me which field it's currently linked to?

I think I'm just too dumb to google it, but I just can't seem to find anything of the sort...

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I could cycle through the controls on the form without a question, but
>   is there a property of the text box telling me which field it's
>   currently linked to?

Yes, that is - as you mention - property ControlSource …

So, loop the controls collection of the form (filter on control type TextBox) and find that (or *those* as it could be) bound to your field.